# Get component from a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

If there is a `JEditorPane` in a `JScrollPane`, how can you get the editor from the scrollpane?

I tried `scrollPane.getComponents()` but the editor wasn't in the list.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport(); 
JEditorPane editorPane = (JEditorPane)viewport.getView();
```

Comment: outch ... was about to post: "naturally getViewportView" but that method unexpectedly doesn't exist, one of those crazy asymetries ;-)

Comment: a shorter way: JEditorPane editorPane = (JEditorPane)scrollPane.getViewport.getView();

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
Component[] components = viewport.getComponents();
```

although you could just have a class field that holds a reference to your editor pane and get it more easily that way.

Edit: as per Jeanette and Rob: the best way to get the single child component held by the viewport is with its `getView()` method.

My initial answer reminds me of a quote from H.L. Mencken:

> "For every complex problem there is a solution that is concise, clear, simple, and wrong."

Comment: JViewport has at most a single child, it has api to access that single child by getView() (might return null if no child). So disagree with @Boro about conciseness ;-)